Flutter Background Service Works on Some Devices but Not Others
I'm working on a Flutter app where I need to implement background services to handle tasks such as fetching data or sending notifications while the app is in the background. The service works perfectly on certain devices, but on others, it fails to run when the app is not active or the device goes to sleep.
Steps to Reproduce:

Implemented background service using a package flutter_background_service.
Tested the app on devices like [Vivo t3x, Motorola, OnePlus, Nothing, Google Pixel 6a].
Noticed that it fails to work on devices like [Vivo Y53, Vivo Y91].

Expected Behavior:
The background service should continue running on all devices even when the app is in the background or when the device goes to sleep.
Actual Behavior:
The background service works on some devices, but it doesn't run on others. I've checked for:

Battery optimization settings.
Permission issues.

Things I’ve Tried:

Checking background and battery optimization settings on the devices.

Ensuring proper permissions are set in the Android manifest (FOREGROUND_SERVICE, BACKGROUND_SERVICE, LOCATION_SERVICE, more).

Using flutter_background_service package to handle background tasks.


